# Android - how to set theme values programmatically (from database values)

Tags: android, xamarin

Is it possible if my theme values are downloadable from server then my mobile theme will change according to what I specify from it?

Example if I have columns [colorPrimary] and [colorAccent] from server then after downloading values, my app theme colors will change accordingly.

This is my current theme.

```
<style name="Base.Theme.Design" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="colorPrimary">#013034</item>
  <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#013034</item>
  <item name="colorAccent">#1490a0</item>
  <item name="android:textColorHint">#9e9e9e</item>
</style>
```

Note: For all downvotes, please leave comment for improvement of this post. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, does my answer work for you?

Comment: Hi Joe :) I know your answer will work perfectly but it is not what I meant on my question so it's a no (just for my part, but if others need it for sure it will work) . What I am trying to achieve is to change the theme values programmatically after downloading values from the host server side .

Comment: @jace - How did you finally approach this problem? I have  somewhat similar requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase remote config to apply that, for example if you have multiple theme options for your app like "Base.Theme.Design_A" and "Base.Theme.Design_B" which are already built-in your app. You can switch between and apply one of these themes by checking a remote property in Firebase remote config. Also you can change old value and fetch the remote values and activate them (not with style file)

```
<defaultsMap>
<entry>
<!-- color entries -->
<entry>
    <key>colorPrimary</key>
    <value>#013034</value>
</entry>
<entry>
    <key>colorPrimaryDark</key>
    <value>#013034</value>
</entry>
```

To change your app's colour dynamically, for elaborate implementations refer to [this](https://segunfamisa.com/posts/firebase-remote-config)

Comment: If I am right, remote config by FireBase will require internet connection continuously ? And from your first suggestion, you are saying that I should have n-number pre-built themes for me to change it right? And lastly, can I use FireBase and MSSQL together on my app if ever? Just want some clarifications :)

Comment: No it will not require internet connection continuously. when you query remote config for a particular value, you'll either get the updated value from the cloud, or whatever default you've supplied locally, First you are going to create default values that control the behavior and appearance of your app. Then, you can later use the Firebase console to override in-app default values.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to change your App's theme dynamically.

You need put two the themes in your `styles.xml` in advance, like this:

```
<style name="AppThemeA" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#aba424</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#9f2020</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#2a6c29</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeB" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#706464</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#831444</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#183150</item>
</style>
```

And use one of them in your codes.

For example, there is button in your `MainActivity`, if you click it, your theme will change to `AppThemeA`, so you need do this in your `MainActivity`'s `OnCreate`:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if ("A".Equals(Intent.GetStringExtra("Theme")))
    {
        SetTheme(Resource.Style.AppThemeA);
    }
    else if("B".Equals(Intent.GetStringExtra("Theme"))) {
        SetTheme(Resource.Style.AppThemeB);
    }

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
    Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.bt);

    button.Click += (sender, e) => {
        Intent intent= new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.PutExtra("Theme","A");
        StartActivity(intent);
        Finish();
    };

}
```